# How to wrap tape around a object?

Tags: modeling

So via the use of Curves > Curve spirals > Archimedian I've made the following:
[image]

Now I want to wrap the tape around the handle to fit the baseball bat mesh perfectly... problem is I can't seem to figure it out. I tried using Shrinkwrap but I only get the following:

[image]

It seems to join with my mess to mess it up. Anyway on how to do this but not manually scaling?

Answer (score 3):

With pivot set to '3D Cursor', assuming the length of your baseball bat is in Z, and with the 'Loop Tools' built-in Add On enabled ...

1. Select a transverse edge loop near the bottom of your tape winding
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> 'Cursor to Selected'
3. Select a vertical set of vertices spanning the height you will want your spiral

[image]

4. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate that span (in real life,
   right-click to leave it where it is, on the surface of your object)
5. <kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide the selection. In the tool region, adjust the count to create as many vertices as you will eventually want on your spiral... (total turns * vertices per turn).

[image]

6. With the vertices in the profile selected, use <kbd>W</kbd> > Loop Tools > Space to distribute them evenly along your profile.
7. <kbd>O</kbd> .. switch on Proportional Editing. Set the Falloff Type to 'Linear'... Select the bottom vertex of your profile alone ... hit <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.  Using the scroll-wheel, adjust the range of your proportional edit to include the top vertex of your profile.

With each wind of your mouse around the 3D cursor, you will introduce a new turn on your spiral, conforming to the surface of the bat.

[image]

Instead of doing this interactively, you could assign a Simple Deform > Twist modifier to the profile, which does the exact same thing. Set Axis to Z, and  Angle set to 360 * your number of turns. That way you can go back and adjust it later, if you need to.